# PHP setting $GLOBALS produces blank result

Tags: php, global

Is there a problem setting a global variable ?

This is INSIDE a function, & in a foreach loop.  These three lines are one after the other (it does not go anywhere else)...

```
    $GLOBALS["nameaa"]=$abl;
    $search_array_log.= "  ADDING GLOBALS NAME - '$ab1'\n";
    $search_array_log.= " GLOBAL NAME1 NOWAa '".$GLOBALS["nameaa"]."'\n";
```

But when viewing the `$search_array_log` data afterwards,  the `GLOBALS` value isnt set.. - its a blank result...

I tried `name` & thought it may be a reserved word, so changed to `nameaa` but the `$GLOBALS["nameaa"]` is still blank.

I do know there may be some issues / processes to follow to send data in/out of functions...   But these three lines are in the same code - No going in/out (as yet) of the function...

Can anyone advise as to what may be the cause as to why this `$GLOBALS` isnt being set ??

Ps `$search_array_log` is being saved/recorded for everything before/after these three lines - its a long text file / log file.

EDIT: `$ab1` does exist as a value & is shown in my logs - `ADDING GLOBALS NAME - $ab1`.

Comment: what do you have inside $ab1 ?

Comment: You are speaking of `$ab1`, as `A-B-ONE`, but use `$abl`, as `A-B-L` in the code

Comment: Thanks.  I should use capital letters in future... instead of the number 1, use another more obvious number that cant be mistaken for lower-case l)

Comment: You should use naming conventions instead of mindlessly typing something like `JHYG` in caps with numbers as well. Awful...

Answer (score 0):

A variable outside function is a global variable like

```
<?php
$abc = 10; //global var
function foo {
     global $abc; // to use global variable inside function
}
?>
```

Hope it help.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?